# Ruby datetime only update date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column on my db which has a datatype of datetime. How can I update this column attribute but just only the date?

For example:

My value is `2014-12-02 04:10:00 UTC`

and I want to update my value with this parameters: `2014-12-03`.

Answer (score 3):

here is a method to change the date part of datetime

```
date_time.change(:year=>new_date.year,:month=>new_date.month,:day=>new_date.day)
```

here `date_time` is your date_time object and `new_date` is the new date you want to set

Comment: Note that this return a new DateTime object and doesn't modify the one that `.change` is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is change the `updated_at` column type to `date` instead `datetime`.
you can use migrations below:

```
change_table :my_table do |t|
  t.change :updated_at, :date
end
```

and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

**UPDATE**

if you don't want to change the db column type, maybe a concern could help.

```
module CustomUpdatedAtFormat
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def current_updated_at
    Time.now.utc.to_date # modify this line for what u need
  end

  def record_timestamps
    false
  end

  included do
    before_update do
      updated_at = current_updated_at
    end

    before_create do
      created_at = Time.now.utc
      updated_at = current_updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

then you could `include CustomUpdatedAtFormat` at the model you need.

Comment: I think they have a timestamp in the database and they only want to change the date component of that timestamp. I don't think they want to change the column type.

Comment: But I still need the time that's why I don't want to change the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I already have an idea about this.

I will get my old data in my db, but the time only.

Something like this.

```
@record = Record.find(1)
@new_datetime = params[:new_date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ' ' + @record.date_time.to_datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

@record.update_column(:date_time, @new_datetime)
```

Thanks.